# How to avoid my app to be terminated, when it's running and tracking my location in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, location, terminate

I am making an app, which needs to keep tracking user's location every time. It can also work in the background mode. The issue is When I use other apps for several times. The other app may cause lots of memory. My app sometimes be terminated by the system. There are no crash logs. So I want to know some reasons. Is there any way to avoid my app to be terminated? Very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent the app the be terminated, but what can you do best to keep it alive is when it enters in background free as much memory as you can - cached images, files... Also stop any running timers, UI updates and everything time consuming. By following the MVC rules, the best implementation is to create a separate class (model) that's only responsible for location updates (with `CLLocationManager` inside, and the class implements its delegation methods). So the only thing in background you should do is collecting the location points received by the `CLLocationManager` and nothing else. Also implement the method `-applicationWillTerminate` in you `AppDelegate`. This method is called only when the app is in background and it's going to be terminated (either by the OS or the user) and inside persist the location points in CoreData for example or however you do it... I have such an approach and so far my app has lived for 24h (with charging of course) without being killed.

Answer (score 2):

App running in the background depend upon memory usage, battery life etc.When there are many app running in the background, your app may get terminated.I do not think you can run your app permanently in background.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. If my app uses less memory, will it reduce the opportunity to be terminated?

Comment: And you can notify user whenever location changes.Follows this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775730/iphone-app-runnung-in-the-background-terminates-after-10-minutes